# dbutils.fs.mount() works for Python but not for R?

Tags: r, azure, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-storage-account

The following code works in a Azure Databricks **Python** cell:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://my-container@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/mount1",
  extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net":dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "my-scope", key = "storagekey")})
```

However, if I try to run this code from an Azure Databricks **R** cell I get an error, can somebody explain what's going on?

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = 'wasbs://my-container@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net',
  mountPoint = '/mnt/mount1',
  extraConfigs = {'fs.azure.account.key.mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net':dbutils.secrets.get(scope = 'my-scope', key = 'storagekey')}
)
```

> Warning in as.list(extraConfigs) : NAs introduced by coercion Warning in as.list(extraConfigs) : NAs introduced by coercion Error in
> "fs.azure.account.key.mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net":dbutils.secrets.get(scope
> = "my-scope",  :    NA/NaN argument Some( Error in
> "fs.azure.account.key.mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net":dbutils.secrets.get(scope
> = "my-scope", : NA/NaN argument ) Error in "fs.azure.account.key.mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net":dbutils.secrets.get(scope
> = "my-scope", : NA/NaN argument

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're trying to use Python syntax for `extraConfigs` parameter, but it's incorrect. In R you need to use following syntax for dicts: `c(key1="value1", key2="value2")`